# $\frac {1}{(x^2+1)^2}$ as a Laurent series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

> How can I write this function $\frac {1}{(z^2+1)^2}$ as a Laurent
>   series around the point $z =i$?

I am struggling with the partial fractions part. It's unreducible. The only thing that came to my mind was: $(z^2+1) = (z-i)(z+i)$ and I remained stuck here. Every  my attemt was a fail (I think they were a nonsense so I won't show it).

My textbook says, the solution is $ \sum _{n=-2} ^{\infty} \frac {(n+3)i^n(z-i)^n}{2^{n+4}}$ , where $z$ is a complex number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)} = \frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}\right]\tag{1} $$
now square both sides and exploit $(1)$ again:
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2} &=& -\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{1}{(z-i)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}-\frac{2}{(z-i)(z+i)}\right]\\ &=& -\frac{1}{4}\left[\color{red}{\frac{1}{(z-i)^2}}\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{i}{z-i}}\color{blue}{-\frac{i}{z+i}}\right]\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now the red terms give the singular part and the blue terms give the regular part of the wanted Laurent series.

Comment: nice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{-1}{(z-i)^2}\frac d{dz}\frac 1{z+i}$$ and $$\frac 1{z+i}=\frac 1{2i+(z-i)}=\frac{-\frac i2}{1-\frac i2(z-i) }$$